# Is this some type of damage to my RAM hardware?

Tags: memory, laptop-repair

I have had a problem with my laptop recently, where it will not start up.  I will be sending it in for repairs, but I wanted to get some input about a possible hardware issue.  I am enclosing here a link to a photo of the RAM hardware, where it appears there may be some type of corrosion, leakage, or other damage to some of the pins.

[image: Problem area indicated in pink]

Does it look like something may be the matter, or am I just overthinking it?

Comment: You can try running [memtest](http://memtest86.com/) to make sure your RAM is operating normally.

Comment: Given the signs of hand resoldering just to the right of that pool of gunk, it is almost certainly flux.  The pool is coming from the one brown pin, the third pin to the right of that one hasn't flowed evenly and may be where someone took a soldering iron to it. Looks like it *might* be shorting to the next pin over or the next pin might be a dry joint.

Answer (score 2):

That just looks like uncleaned [flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_(metallurgy)), a material used in the manufacturing of [printed circuit boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board). It should be removed once the board is completely assembled, but some manufacturers do a sloppy job and fail to completely clean it.

It's generally harmless, but you can remove it using isopropyl alcohol. Be sure to remove the battery (if possible) and that the board is completely dry before you turn the system back on.

Comment: Remove/disconnect the battery before you do that